# Adding own framework or library to AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to add my custom package to AOSP under `frameworks/opt/mypackage`.

I provided an `Android.mk` Makefile with the following content:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := mypackage
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

In an other framework, I was out to use this package. For example in the telephony package.

But unfortunately the telephony framework is not able to use my package. I added my package to the `LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES` variable in telephony's `Android.mk` but when the code is executed it gives me `01-11 16:51:01.835: E/AndroidRuntime(1789): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available`

Did I miss something?

EDIT: setting `include $(BUILD_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY)` instead of `include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)` in my Makefile and adding my package to the `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` of the frameworks works well. Nevertheless: the question is why does it not work with a non-static library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you need a permission file for local libraries.

Follow these steps:

1. add your lib name "mypackage" to `LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES` in your Android.mk of the package you want to use it.
2. add the xml permission file like this:

com.mypackage.platform_library.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<permissions>
    <library name="com.mypackage.platform_library"
        file="/system/framework/com.mypackage.platform_library.jar"/>
</permissions>
```

This file must be placed in /system/etc/permissions on the device. Make also sure that your mypackage.jar is at the specified location on the device.

3. In your AndroidManifest use `<uses-library android:name="com.mypackage.platform_library" />`

[Here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/device/sample/frameworks/PlatformLibrary/) you can find an example.

Comment: This path (/system/etc/permissions) is for built rom; Where should I paste that XML file in AOSP (before compile it) ?

Comment: Wherever you want. Just make sure that this file is copied to the correct location in the image. You can achieve this in the following way in your Product config: PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/com.mypackage.platform_library.xml:/system/etc/permissions/com.mypackage.platform_library.xml another way would be to use BUILD_PREBUILT in your Android.mk

Comment: If I want to set permission to a prebuilt application, What should I changes in that snippet code? Is that even possible to add extra permission to a prebuild app?