# How to add extra permission to a prebuilt application (no source code) in AOSP

Tags: bash, shell, android-permissions, android-source, android.mk

I have an application that doesn't have a specific android permission(for example `android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`).

1. I don't have its source code.
2. I'm working on an AOSP.

I prebuilt this application like:

1. Put APK in `/device/model/apps/HERE`
2. Add these snippet codes in Android.mk:

`define PREBUILT_templateByMe
    LOCAL_MODULE := $(1)
    LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
    LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
    LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $$(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
    LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := $(2)
    include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
endef`

`define PREBUILT_APP_templateByMe
    include $$(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
    $(call PREBUILT_templateByMe, $(1), $(2))
endef`

`prebuilt_appsByMe := \
    myapp`

`$(foreach app,$(prebuilt_appsByMe), \
    $(eval $(call PREBUILT_APP_templateByMe, $(app),)))
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))`

It's work very well, and myapp prebuilt to OS.

Now I want to add that specific android permission(`android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`) to myapp.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889193/adding-own-framework-or-library-to-aosp), [this](http://karthiksden.blogspot.de/2011/03/copying-data-files-using-androidmk.html) and many other documents, but I don't know the content of this XML file for an application; Or is it even possible?!
(Does these links helpful to direct me in the right direction about content of XML file? [this](https://github.com/InsomniaAOSP/platform_external_sepolicy/blob/master/tools/setool/tests/res/com/seandroid/tools/1.xml) and [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sepolicy/+/b19665c39da76c0e24c8cd9583e30c4a50567510%5E!/))

---

I tried another way, but didn't work(preinstall application and add permission by shell script:
**Note:** First of all, I should say it worked before, on another custom AOSP, but didn't work on this one!

1. Put APK in `/device/model/apps/HERE`
2. Add this snippet code in Android.mk

`include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := myapp.apk
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
    LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := ETC
    LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/preinstall
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myapp.apk
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)`

`include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := preinstall.sh
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
    LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := ETC
    LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/preinstall
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := preinstall.sh
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)`

3. Content of preinstall.sh:

`#!/system/bin/sh`
`MARK=/data/local/symbol_thirdpart_apks_installed
PKGS=/system/preinstall/`
`if [ ! -e $MARK ]; then
echo "booting the first time, so pre-install some APKs."`
`busybox find $PKGS -name "*\.apk" -exec sh /system/bin/pm install {} \;`
`touch $MARK
echo "OK, installation complete."
fi`
`busybox sh /system/bin/pm grant com.example.myapp android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION;`

4. Call this shell script as service on boot in init.rc file, like:
   `on boot
   start preinstallByMe`

`service preinstallByMe /system/bin/sh /system/preinstall/preinstall.sh
    class main
    user root
    group root
    disabled
    oneshot`

But seems it's not call.

4. Even these snippet codes in init.rc file not working too:

   1. `service installapk /system/preinstall/preinstall.sh
      class main
      oneshot`
   2. `on boot
      exec /system/preinstall/preinstall.sh`
   3. `busybox /system/preinstall/preinstall.sh`
   4. `pm grant com.example.myapp android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION;`

**Note:** If I call preinstall from shell manually, it's work.
**P.S:** If your not allowed to call your script,  you can add permission to it by adding something like this in `/system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h` :

`{ 00755, AID_ROOT,      AID_ROOT,      0, "system/preinstall/preinstall.sh"},`

Cause second way(preinstall and add permission by shell), in this custom AOSP, doesn't work, I'm going to add that specific android permission to my app, from beginning,  via prebuilt; **But** if anyone knows what's wrong with the second solution, I'm appreciate it.

Comment: You can decompile apk file and modify manifest in it, there are tools for that, for example: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Comment: @Mixaz I'm using one of the GApps applications. So it's important to keep the original certificate.

Comment: Can you explain how you add the specific android permission to your app via prebuilt?

Comment: @ChrisSchiffhauer Do you working on AOSP? WHat is your Android OS version? Did you try 4th steps? (Add your script in init.rc file). Anyway, you can look at this link too: https://github.com/Drjacky/Install-Google-Play-Manually

Comment: Yes, I'm building AOSP 7.1 with a background service I wrote and I want to pre-grant location permissions to the service. I'll try your init.rc implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be eligible for system permissions, you should put your APKs in `/system/priv-app` folder.
**Note:** Prior to Kitkat, all APKs on the system partition could use those permissions.

The sample snippet code to copy APK to `/system/priv-app`:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := apkname.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/priv-app
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := apkname.apk
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

For more information:

> Some system apps are more system than others
>   "signatureOrSystem" permissions are no longer available to all apps residing en the /system partition. Instead, there is a new /system/priv-app directory, and only apps whose APKs are in that directory are allowed to use signatureOrSystem permissions without sharing the platform cert. This will reduce the surface area for possible exploits of system- bundled applications to try to gain access to permission-guarded operations.
>
> The ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM flag continues to mean what it is said in the documentation: it indicates that the application APK was bundled on the /system partition. A new hidden flag FLAG_PRIVILEGED has been introduced that reflects the actual right to access these permissions.

[ Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20104400/421467 ]

**Update:**
Walkthrough: https://github.com/Drjacky/Install-Google-Play-Manually

Answer (score 2):

In shell script file, you have to use:

```
pm grant com.example.myapp android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
```

and copy shell script to /system/bin/

and in init.rc, you execute shell after boot completed:

```
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
   exec /system/bin/preinstall.sh
```

I've successed with this

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the **main** framework manifest in :

```
frameworks\base\core\res\Manifest.xml
```

And change the permission `protectionLevel:` value to `"normal"`, that way as a `priv-app` (Even if not built with the framework key) you should automatically grant all normal permissions, just bear in mind you causing a security bridge for that specific permission.

Comment: Do you mean "framework" is "platform"? And as you said, it's causing a security bridge for that specific permission.

Comment: It is unnecessary to cripple the security of the entire system as a work-around for a single application. There are more recent answers to this post that explain how to change the Android.mk to grant the necessary app permissions to a prebuilt apk.